# GPIO Newbie, can i connect this Crazepony FPV Camera to the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, pigpio

I am a complete noob when it comes to RPi and GPIO

I want to connect 2x[this Crazepony FPV Camera 1.2G 1000TVL 1/4 CMOS 2.8mm Lens FOV170 Degree NTSC Mini FPV Camera](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071L3QK5P) to the RPi over GPIO pins, but don't even know where to start.

Is connecting this camera even possible? Would i just be getting raw binary waveform data without some intermediate chip that knows how to interpret the video feed into packets?

Additionally, since its a drone project I will also be hooking up 4 ESCs to controll brushless motors, are there enough GPIO pins for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The camera output is analog composite video and Raspberry doesn't have analog video input.

There is analog composite video capture USB devices on the market.